# how to automatically delete specific rows in excel file?

Tags: vb.net, excel, batch-file

Situation: every 2 weeks we need to download 3 Excel workbooks from a website, each time we need to open these 3 files and delete always the same rows, for example in the first downloaded Excel workbook we need to delete the first 4 rows, in the 2nd Excel workbook we need to delete the first 4 rows and then the 6th row, etc... What would be the best way to approach this? Could this eventually be done from within a DOS batch file or a VB script? Or is something more advanced required? Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A VB script could do it.  I'd suggest you create a new workbook, and record a macro into that workbook which does what you want.  Then you could put a button onto your new workbook to run the macro.  As long as all workbook filenames each time and rows to be delated are identical, that *should* work.  Bear in mind, though, that I sometimes find that it's necessary to clean up the macros that excel records, in order to make them more robust.

Comment: Since it's a new file each time I'd suggest putting the macro inside your 'personal' excel file and link the macro to a button on your excel menu.  This way you don't have to load another spread sheet to talk with the other three.

Comment: FYI @user1875017 , if you found this answer helpful, it's customary to mark it as the accepted answer, and/or mark it as useful.